# JtabbedPanes in Multiple classes using GUI Builder

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I am using netbeans GUI builder and im trying to figure out a way to have each pane in a different class. For example tab one and all its buttons and jazz will be in one class, and then tab two and all its buttons will be in a different class. If you know a way please let me know how.

Comment: Create a new `JPanel` based class, add what ever you want to it.  Open you the class with the `JTabbedPane` in it, drag you "panel" class onto.  Now throw the form editor away and do it by hand, while it's a powerful tool, it will teach you bad habits

Comment: I do agree with you about the form editor however i have never been taught anything with Gui and for a school project i now have to use it. Also i do not understand what you mean before hand when you actually answered my question.

Comment: Like how do i drag it in?

Comment: Wait i think i understand actually thanks i appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, any component based class which is in your projects class path (libraries, projects, jars, source code) can be added to the form editor (so long as it is compiled and can be instantiated without error)

Start by creating you a `JPanel` based form/class

[image: Panel based form]

Add what ever content you need to it and build what ever functionality you need

[image: Build it up]

Create another `JPanel` based form and add a `JTabbedPane` to it...

[image: Tabbed Pane]

Make sure you save and compile your classes first and the drag you original panel based form onto the `JTabbedPane`...

[image: Drag]

You now have a new tab :)

[image: New tab]

You can also do a lot of it by hand (fixing hand code with form editor code if you have to), have a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks that makes thing much more easy